# weka decision tree java

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree

I want to make a list of all the predictions.

I have this code :

```
//Get File
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PATH + "TempArffFile.arff"));

        //Get the data
        Instances data = new Instances(reader);
        reader.close();

        //Setting class attribute 
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        //Make tree
        J48 tree = new J48();
        String[] options = new String[1];
        options[0] = "-U"; 
        tree.setOptions(options);
        tree.buildClassifier(data);

        //Print tree
        System.out.println(tree);
```

It works fine i can see the tree printed , but dont know how to work with that from here.
I want to make a list for each root how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like a list of all the testing predictions, you could use the following code (sample code provided [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code)):

```
 import weka.core.Instances;
 import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
 import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
 ...
 Instances train = ...   // from somewhere
 Instances test = ...    // from somewhere
 // train classifier
 Classifier cls = new J48();
 cls.buildClassifier(train);
 // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
 Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
 eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
 System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
```

You could also use [J48.classifyInstance()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html#classifyInstance%28weka.core.Instance%29) to predict a single instance, if you prefer to go that way.

Comment: that not what i ment. 
i have this resoult : title <= 1: bad (4.0)
title > 1
|   positionMatch <= 1
|   |   countryCode <= 1-> good
|   |   countryCode > 1-> bad
|   positionMatch > 1-> good.

now i have some item and want to check if it's good or not.
title =2 , position =0 , country code = 0 => so it's good.
how can i do that checking in java?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to get all of the rules in your tree?  I'm sorry,  but the question appeared to ask for the predictions.

Comment: my mistake i'll ask a new one. your code does work for prediction